# No Cognitive Services in the Microsoft namespace?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am getting started with the Azure services inside of Unity and am getting the error:

Assets\Scripts\HelloWorld.cs(8,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CognitiveServices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This might be something simple but ive put the key and regions inside the SpeechConfig and my namespaces are as follows:
...

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
using UnityEngine.Android;
#endif
#if PLATFORM_IOS
using UnityEngine.iOS;
using System.Collections;
#endif
```

...

Have the namespaces changed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the namespace. If you are in Visual Studio, in your project files, you should see 'References'. Right click and **Add Reference**.

Comment: I'm actually in VSC.  I downloaded the Nuget package manager in order to install the reference to the services and tried to install from the Command Palette via "Nuget Add Packages. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech  I used the install command from this page but it came back with a "no matching result found" message.

Comment: Also installed dotnet via the NET sdk for windows to command line and gut this mess after using the command "dotnet add package Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech" 
Could not find any project in `C:\Users\Owner\`.
Usage: dotnet add <PROJECT> package [options] <PACKAGE_NAME>
Arguments:
  <PROJECT>        The project file to operate on. If a file is not specified, the command will search the current directory for one.
  <PACKAGE_NAME>   The package reference to add.                                                                
I'm not sure how to link tje unity project in command.